# the same variable has a different value in the code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, console

```
const [arrUserID, setArrUserID] = useState([])

   const fetchUser = async () => {
    try {
        const owner = await axios({
            url: `${baseUrl}/addcryptos/owner/${userid}`,
            method: 'get'
        })
        const { events } = owner.data
        for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {   
            const reducer = (accumulator, curr) => accumulator + curr;
            setArrUserID(arrUserID.push(events[i].id)) // return id of 'events' in array [1, 1027, 1027, 3087]
            console.log(arrUserID.toString()) // return 1,1027,1027,3087
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}


  const problem = useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        if (arrUserID.toString() !== '')
            try {
                const data = await axios({
                    url: `http://myurl/yes?id=${arrUserID.toString()}`,
                    method: 'get'
                })
               console.log(arrUserID) //THERE IS A PROBLEM -> return 4 because my array length is 4 but it's expected to be "1,1027,1027,3087"
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
    })();
}, []);
```

so i don't understand why when i console.log my "arrUserID" is one time = `[1027, 1, 453 ....]`  and one time egal to `array.length` ?

if somebody know what is the problem that would be great beacause i don't have any idea

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to set a new state for an array is through spread syntax.
When you do:

`setArrUserID(arrUserID.push(events[i].id))`

you're setting the value of `arrUserId` to be the 4 because `.push()` returns the new length of the array, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Try doing:

`setArrUserID([...arrUserId, events[i].id])`

Comment: hey Croix, thanks for your answer ! so, when i do what you tell me i have a result like: [1027] [2340] [1027]. but i really want  to have a result with all value of arrays, separated by à coma in console like: 1071, 2340, 1027

Comment: Can you try: `console.log(arrUserId.join(", "))`

Comment: Is `events[i].id` an array or a string?